# PnP Provisioning templates in PnP Js

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, typescript, pnp-js-core

XML-based PnP Provisioning templates are available to be consumed via SharePoint PnP PowerShell.

**Question**: Is there something similar for provisioning lists via JavaScript/TypeScript via pre-created template?

I really like the ability of creating the lists manually and saving them to a template later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSOM does not provide a similar way to create a list.

According to my test results, jsom cannot even get the existing custom list template.

PNP js does not provide a similar way to create a list.